# Windows Phone exception popup

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, popup

I would like to show the popup window warning that internet connection is not available, but I do not know how to pop a simple pop up window on the screen (something like text block) and then close the app after OK.

```
 void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {
        SyndicationFeed feed;
        try {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result)) {
                feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
                lista.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
            }
        } catch (WebException we) { POP IT HERE then close the app;}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
MessageBox.Show("you text");
```

Comment: Ok that's great but I would like to quit the app after clicking ok on that message box.

Comment: @RobertKilar do not do it, it is against the guidelines and you would probably fail the certification

Comment: So what: then back to the empty screen(no content was downloaded?

Comment: @RobertKilar I do not know what your app is supposted to do but I would recomend informing the user about the error and giving him a chance to retry the action

Answer (score 2):

You should use this:

```
MessageBox.Show(we.Message);
```